# Compare IEnumerable with Data in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I compare data from `IEnumerable` with data in `IsolatedStorage`.
Here's my code:

```
        var  data1 = from query in document.Descendants("Services")
        select new Ser 
        {
            name = query.Element("Name") !=  null
            ? query.Element("Name").Value
            : string.Empty,
        };
        ReportList.ItemsSource = data1;
        // ...
        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {        
                string IsoKey = (((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as Ser).name;
                _isoSettings.Add(IsoKey, IsoKey);
                _isoSettings.Save();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Эта служба уже в исключениях");
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Ignore" Click="MenuItem_Click"  />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="Coral" />
```

And:

```
 foreach (string keyCollect in keysCollect)
        {
            returtStr += keyCollect;
        }
```

I want to compare data1 with returtStr. And don't show equal data in ListBox.
Something like this:

```
var comparedata = data1.Except(returtStr);
```

But I have an error:

> Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Except(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\gromov\SkyDrive\Server Monitor\Server
>   Monitor\MainPage.xaml.cs  143 29  Server Monitor

and:

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'    C:\Users\gromov\SkyDrive\Server
>   Monitor\Server Monitor\MainPage.xaml.cs   143 29  Server Monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Except` is used to find the element of a collection that are not contained in another. Since `returtStr` is a string and not a collection, it cannot possibly work.

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
var compareData = data1.Where(s => !keysCollect.Contains(s.name));
```

Or:

```
var compareData = data1.Select(s => s.name).Except(keysCollect);
```

Comment: for second line
Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<ServerMon.MainPage.Jup,int,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return typy

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool

Comment: For the first. There is no Contains for keysCollect

Comment: @GromaGrom What is the type of `keysCollect`?

Comment: ICollection keysCollect = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Keys;

Comment: Then you can replace by `var compareData = data1.Where(s => !IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(s.name));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var  data1 = (from query in document.Descendants("Services")
select new Ser { name = Convert.ToString(query.Element("Name") )
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ServerMon.MainPage.Jup>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments  144 31 

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ServerMon.MainPage.Jup>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<char>' .cs 144 31